# Is there any downside in std::get_temporary_buffer and std::raw_storage_iterator?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, iterator, allocator

Recently I heard of `get_temporary_buffer` and `raw_storage_iterator`'s, which seem to be great. Almost in each copy it's possible to avoid initialization of N elements, which could improve performance significantly.

But I have worked with C++ pretty much, and didn't see anywhere usage of whose functionalities. Is there any downside? Why people don't use them that often? Why shouldn't I use them every time I want to copy (in a new container, of course)?

Comment: Do note that both of these are deprecated in C++17.

Comment: The downside seems to be its [deprecated in c++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer).

Comment: Why is this better than [`std::allocator::allocate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/allocate)? It also returns uninitialized storage. `get_temporary_buffer` can return also less than you request, which could be a problem.

Comment: People who know what they are doing deprecated those for a reason. You can read around this paper: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0174r2.html#3.2

Comment: The whole fact that it could allocate less storage then you need and you have to check for that makes it a no go for me.  I'll stick with a new like construction.

Comment: Straustrup was telling about it so enthusiastically, that I thought it's really a beast, but yes, agree, it's a kind of 'bad new'. @DeiDei, thanks for good resource!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tim Song for explaining this to me today (for probably not the first time). Recording it here for posterity.

The problem with `raw_storage_iterator` is that **it is impossible to use safely in the presence of exceptions.**

Consider this implementation of a non-allocator-aware `Vector<T>`:

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::reallocate(int newcap) {
    T *newbuf = (T*)malloc(newcap * sizeof(T));
    Auto( free(newbuf); );
    std::copy(
        buf_, buf_ + size_,
        std::raw_storage_iterator<T*, T>(newbuf)
    );
    std::swap(buf_, newbuf);
    std::swap(cap_, newcap);
    std::destroy(newbuf, newbuf + size_);
}
```

That `Auto` is [the `Auto` macro](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/08/11/the-auto-macro/), a.k.a. `ON_SCOPE_EXIT`. It ensures that we correctly `free` the old allocation when we hit the closing curly brace of the function; and also that we'll free the *new* allocation if an exception is thrown before we get to the `swap`s.

However, if an exception is thrown during the `std::copy`, freeing the allocation isn't our only responsibility! `std::copy` may have constructed some number of `T` objects in `newbuf`. Those `T` objects themselves might manage resources. If an exception is thrown, we *must* call the destructors of all those `T` objects before freeing `newbuf`. Otherwise, we have a resource leak.

So, how many `T` objects should we destroy? ...We have no idea.

> `raw_storage_iterator` is impossible to use safely in the presence of exceptions.

---

[`std::uninitialized_copy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_copy) (which also dates back to C++03) does not have this problem.

```
template<class T>
void Vector<T>::reallocate(int newcap) {
    T *newbuf = (T*)malloc(newcap * sizeof(T));
    Auto( free(newbuf); );
    std::uninitialized_copy(buf_, buf_ + size_, newbuf);
    std::swap(buf_, newbuf);
    std::swap(cap_, newcap);
    std::destroy(newbuf, newbuf + size_);
}
```

`std::uninitialized_copy` counts how many objects it has successfully constructed. If an exception is thrown while constructing the `it`'th object, then `uninitialized_copy` will destroy every object in the range [`first`, `it`) before it rethrows the exception. Therefore we have no resource leak in that case.

This is the fundamental reason that `raw_storage_iterator` was removed and `uninitialized_copy` was not. The former is exception-unsafe; the latter is exception-safe.

---

Bonus: Neither `raw_storage_iterator` nor `uninitialized_copy` is allocator-aware, which means they can't literally form part of the implementation of an allocator-aware container like `std::vector`. Every vendor must roll their own `__uninitialized_copy_a` to use internally. But allocator-awareness was not a factor in the deprecation of `raw_storage_iterator` as far as I can tell. The killer was exception-unsafety.